# Good wind-screen for a bicycle?

Tags: winter

I recently constructed my own windshield for my bicycle using Lexan and wood. It works great but it is hand-made thing and I *might* be willing to buy a premade one that is curved (mine has a 90 degree angle).

But is there a good one available?

Comment: I'd like to see a pic of the one you made.

Comment: I haven't seen a windscreen on a bike in over 20 years.

Comment: Windscreens/fairings are common on recumbent bicycles

Comment: No idea of quality, but googling "[bicycle fairing upright](https://www.google.com/search?q=bicycle+fairing+upright)" finds some options. Some of the recumbent fairings look like they might be possible to mount on a regular upright bicycle.

Comment: Added a [tag:fairing] tag.

Comment: @Mox - Fairings are most common with recumbents. What kind of bike do you have?

Comment: @freiheit -- Yep, I probably have seen them on bents.  My mind would block those out, I suspect.  Last one I remember on an upright was 20-odd years ago on a group tour.

Answer (score 2):

[Zzipper](http://www.zzipper.com/Products/prod_upright.php) makes fairings for upright bikes.

I haven't used a Zzipper or Windwrap fairing myself, but they're well regarded by the people in the forums at bentrideronline.com , who I've gotten good advice from about 2 recumbents I've owned.

Windwrap is sold by t-cycle.com/collections/windwrap-fairings and they're made for recumbents, but the smaller XT and XT mini might fit an upright. It looks like most of of the mounts are being redesigned at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In The Netherlands they are very common, because we used to place a child-seat on the handlebars.

[Here's a link to a second-hand website](https://www.marktplaats.nl/z.html?query=windscherm+fiets&categoryId=0&postcode=&distance=0), that offers a lot of windscreens. For some reason its in Dutch, but I'm sure you can get lots of inspiration, and maybe even get a cheap one.

Comment: 7 years later - that website seems to list more cars than anything else.  Consider adding a couple of photos to your answer to make it change-resistant.  Link-only answers like this are discouraged.

Comment: I still find many of the child bike wind screens on the site (maybe it helps I am in the same country as the site.) But those are screens to keep your child out of the wind, not sure whether they work for adults.

Answer (score 0):

It's best you either buy one or make your's a bit curve (if you are able to do it) if you want to be faster. Because a 90 degree windshield is not aerodynamic. if you are happy with your windshield, keep it.